# How to apply width ease-in-out transition to element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Attempting to apply a transition to this image, I can't understand why this does not work and the width styling is applied instantly versus transitioning out from its current width as expected by the function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img style="" id="myImg" src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/S9c1b79c0b59442d0b36ea6aea9cd266fO/Super-Cat-Bed-Warm-Sleeping-Cat-Nest-Soft-Long-Pluh-Best-Pet-Dog-Bed-For-Dogs.jpg.jpg" height="98">

<p>Click the button to change the width of the image to 300px.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myImg").style.display = "flex";
  document.getElementById("myImg").style.transition = "width 2s";
  document.getElementById("myImg").style.width = "300px";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is so much code there, I would take a look at [mcve] first.

Comment: Apologies, done, this should be easier.

Comment: Thank you. Its a lot easier for people to assist when the bare minimum code is posted instead of going through a bunch of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you are having is that the attribute you are transitioning on, should be declared initially. No matter if its inline or in CSS.

So I changed your code with a random width instead of height, and it transitions now.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myImg").style.display = "flex";
  document.getElementById("myImg").style.transition = "width 2s";
  document.getElementById("myImg").style.width = "300px";
}
```

```html
<img style="" id="myImg" src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/S9c1b79c0b59442d0b36ea6aea9cd266fO/Super-Cat-Bed-Warm-Sleeping-Cat-Nest-Soft-Long-Pluh-Best-Pet-Dog-Bed-For-Dogs.jpg.jpg" width="105">

<p>Click the button to change the width of the image to 300px.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, just reproduced my error simply. Some element/styling is clearly interfering with my transition, I have a preset width/height set on my webpage for an image and the transition instantly occurs regardless (setup exactly like this). Works for some elements, setup the same way on other elements and it does not trigger. Luckily only one nest of elements to work with.

Comment: FIXED! Rather setting the styling, style="display:none", directly to my element and changing this upon clicking my element I set the styling of display to flex and added overflow:hidden. I set the nested elements off the page (overflow:hidden helps here) and now the transition executes. Adding display:none directly through html by style="" breaks the transition. If I remove it, everything is normal. Note: only when attempting to execute through Javascript, for example, you will change the height of an image to 100% on a button click, but before, javascript changes display to flex. It breaks it